# Modelbuilder Iterator on Table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

Will the ESRI  ModelBuilder 10.1 iterator select a value from field in a filegeodatabase table?
If so then can this be joined to a feature class and exported or copied?

I am working with property appraiser data and for example  one parcel of land may sell up to 10 times in a year, which is in a table, the parcels are features.  I would like to select, say all the parcels that have sold twice in one year and then join to the a parcel map.

So I would like to use Iterator to select those sales from a table,  and then join to a parcel feature, copy features then move on to next group of Sale, say Sales 3. 
I do this somewhat manually know with modelbuilder.

Comment: You would not select a single value with an iterator, it would return an entire row which you could join, is that what you want?

Comment: From the returned row, you could then use the [Get Field Value Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Get_Field_Value/004000000006000000/) to retrieve the value for a particular field

Comment: What is the purpose of wanting to iterate? Are you just wanting to append values from a column in a table to the feature class? If so then you can use the Join Field GP tool.

Comment: The purpose is to select from a table sales by groups,  Sales_1, then Sales_2 and then join each sale to a parcel map. Many of the parcels have been sold multiple times in a year, so I'm trying to join the first sale with a parcel, then the second sale of the same parcel etc.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with those clarifications, please?  To learn how comments and questions interact I recommend http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: Yes Hombydd, that is what I would like to do. But select maybe 100 rows that have Sales Grp 1, join to a feature class, copy features, then iterate to Sales Grp 2 automatically, join to a feature class etc..

Comment: What does your model so far look like w.r.t. this bit of functionality?